# How To show blank datepicker when DB value is null

Tags: c#, winforms, datepicker

I've got a SQL DB column for DateTime Birthday on a customer object. The database allows that field to be null, but occasionally our users populate the data (from another system) with `1/1/1900`.

I'd like to have my DatePicker field show nothing when the date in the DB is either null or `DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000")`. (It doesn't have to be fully blank, but can have the DatePicker field's standard default of `" / / "`.

I've been trying this:

```
dtBirthday.Value = customer.Birthday.HasValue ? customer.CustomerOptions.Birthday.Value : DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000");
```

That works fairly well for the null birthdays, but doesn't allow for the date in `customer.Birthday` actually being `DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000")`.

**Update**
I did, in fact, google this, and attempted to use

```
            var nullDate = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000");
            if (customer.Birthday.Value == nullDate)
            {
                dtBirthday.Format = eDateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                dtBirthday.CustomFormat = " ";
                dtBirthday.Value = DateTime.FromOADate(0);
                dtBirthday.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dtBirthday.Format = eDateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                dtBirthday.CustomFormat = "M/d/yyyy";
                dtBirthday.Value = customer.Birthday.Value;
                dtBirthday.Enabled = true;
            }
            //dtBirthday.Value = customer.Birthday.HasValue ? customer.Birthday.Value : DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000");
            if (customer.Anniversary.Value == nullDate)
            {
                dtAnniv.Format = eDateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                dtAnniv.CustomFormat = " ";
                dtAnniv.Value = DateTime.FromOADate(0);
                dtAnniv.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dtAnniv.Format = eDateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                dtAnniv.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
                dtAnniv.Value = customer.Anniversary.Value;
                dtAnniv.Enabled = true;
            }
            //dtAnniv.Value = customer.Anniversary.HasValue ? customer.Anniversary.Value : DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000");
```

It does just about exactly what I want, except that the empty fields are completely disabled, even though I've specifically set them to enabled=true.

Comment: Try searching for "nullable datetimepicker", look at any of the 25,000 hits.

Comment: Thanks for opening with an insult. Always appreciated. In response to your amazingly polite reply, I will say: I have checked google, and all I found was a tonne of people overloading the datepicker, which isn't something I want to do. I know when the field initially loads, with no data going into it, the field displays " / / ". I just want to be able to do that.

Comment: Why do you not want to inherit the DateTimePicker control? since that gives you the solution you want.

Comment: What control is this exactly? Please include namespace. We used a 3rd party control set that used EditValue instead of Value but I'm not sure what you're using.

Comment: Your control being disabled is a different issue than what you originally posted.  So, is your question about a blank DateTimePicker, or about the control being disabled?

Comment: It's a standard WinForms DatePicker control. It doesn't allow nulls, doesn't allow strings. If there was a "DateTime.Null" in C#, I'd use that in a heartbeat.

Comment: Actually, it just occurred to me that if I don't have a value I want to display... I can just not set the field to have a value. Updating the ticket with that now.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, I think you want the text field to be empty when the birthday is actually null.  Why not just populate it with an empty string:

```
txtBirthday.Value = 
    customer.Birthday.HasValue ? 
    customer.CustomerOptions.Birthday.Value.ToString() : 
    string.Empty;
```

Comment: Mainly because ".Value" is actually formatted to DateTime, and won't take a string.

Comment: @PKD -- which is why I called `ToString()` on it.  See my example.

Comment: `txtBirthday.Value` is a DateTime. It doesn't accept strings of any sort.

Comment: `txtBirthday.Value = birthday == string.Empty ? string.Empty : customer.Anniversary.Value.ToString();` was my test of that, using `var birthday = customer.Birthday.Value == DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000") ? string.Empty : customer.Birthday.Value.ToString();` as my birthday string.

Comment: I named the field long before learning what the thing was, and I'm essentially a lazy bastard who doesn't want to rename it at this point. :)

Comment: Lazy?  Just right-click on it and "Refactor > rename".

Answer (score 0):

After attempting several dozen different methods, none of which really did what I want, it occurred to me that I could just *not set the value*.

```
var nullDate = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000");
if (customer.CustomerOptions.Birthday.HasValue && customer.CustomerOptions.Birthday.Value != nullDate)
{
    dtBirthday.Value = customer.CustomerOptions.Birthday.Value;
}

if (customer.CustomerOptions.Anniversary.HasValue && customer.CustomerOptions.Anniversary.Value != nullDate)
{
    dtAnniv.Value = customer.CustomerOptions.Anniversary.Value;
}
```